Same function comes to JIT multiple times in .NET PROFILER
I have developed my own .NET profiler (C++) using CORPROFILER API. And am doing the instrumentation that calls C# helper assembly file.
I have set the following event mask
ProfilerInfo->SetEventMask(
COR_PRF_DISABLE_TRANSPARENCY_CHECKS_UNDER_FULL_TRUST | COR_PRF_MONITOR_EXCEPTIONS | COR_PRF_USE_PROFILE_IMAGES
| COR_PRF_MONITOR_JIT_COMPILATION | COR_PRF_MONITOR_MODULE_LOADS);
My question is, Some functions comes to JITcompilationstarted callback repeatedly. Then my profiler getting down because of this issue. How to avoid same function comes to JIT multiple times?
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void Builder:EnsureCapacity(System.Int32) 2540 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void DisposableData:Release() 2540 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void Builder:EnsureCapacity(System.Int32) 6656 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void DisposableData:Release() 6656 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void Builder:EnsureCapacity(System.Int32) 2540 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void DisposableData:Release() 2540 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void Builder:EnsureCapacity(System.Int32) 6656 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void DisposableData:Release() 6656 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void Builder:EnsureCapacity(System.Int32) 2540 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void DisposableData:Release() 2540 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void Builder:EnsureCapacity(System.Int32) 6656 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void DisposableData:Release() 6656 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void Builder:EnsureCapacity(System.Int32) 2540 PID: 6020
Wed May 15 12:58:07 2024 - [INFO1] System.Void DisposableData:Release() 2540 PID: 6020
PID: 6020
How to avoid the same function from instrumentation?

see the Remarks section here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilercallback-jitcompilationstarted-method#remarks

Generic methods are the more obvious cause, they get jitted for each distinct T (ref type, any of the value types).  Might be ArrayBuilder<T>.EnsureCapacity(), nothing to look at to see how the name got generated.
